Images are not displayed as expected in tableau image pallet
I'm trying to assign images via tableau image pallet as shown below..

However the new images 5 out of 7 are not displaying properly.. I have tried changing the images into Jpg/jpeg and few more but still its showing as circle. Why this is happening and any solutions we have ?

Not a solution, but try checking the properties of the ones that are coming in cleanly, this seems like the "circle" pictures may exceed the max resolutions for shapes. Also make sure you completely close and re-open Tableau each time you make and save changes to your shapes file, this folder gets cached when Tableau is launched and does not refresh when new changes are made to it while Tableau is open.
